# phpMyAdmin MySQL connectivity not working new setup

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to login into phpMyAdmin as a part of installation and when I click on phpMyAdmin under "localhost" it comes with a username and password, when I enter the root and password below error comes up, has checked `config.inc`, and changed false into true like this

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = True;
```

But I cannot login with follwing error

> mysqli::real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
>
> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Answer (score 1):

See: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14220

This should allow access, execute it from the mysql command line

```sql
ALTER USER root@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypassword';
```